# Hibernate : Resultset mapping in to Map<EntityTypeId,List<EntitiyIds>>

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, resultset, named-query

We have a table which contains data like below

```
id  entity_type_id  entity_id
1          1          1234
2          1          2356
3          1          7896
4          1          4321
5          2          1234
6          2          9876
7          2          5289
8          2          4568
```

And I wrote query as follow to get data. How can I modify this query to return it as  list of entitiyIds as value and entityTypeId as key.

```
<query name="getAllEntities">
<![CDATA[
    SELECT e.entity_type_id, e.entity_id from entity as e
]]>
</query>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like below

```
<query name="getAllEntities">
<![CDATA[
    SELECT new Map(e.entity_type_id as et_id, e.entity_id as e_id) from entity as e
]]>
</query>
```

Refer [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select) for more details

Comment: Hey Ankur, I already tried that but it returns List<Map<key,Value>> where key is either 0 or 1 with column values mapped to it.

Comment: Is there any way to get result as Map<EntityTypeId,List<EntitiyIds>> using named-sql-query?